# Destructuring syntax array item and remainder

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I'm trying to master destructuring assignment syntax to accomplish the following:

I have an array of items, say `const arr = ['a','b','c']`, which I want to map into another array of arrays, where each item is a remainder from picking items out of initial array, i.e. `[['b','c'],['a','c'],['a','b']]`

For that purpose I'm trying to do

```
arr.map((_,i) => ([arr[i],...rest] = arr, rest))
```

And that returns

```
[['b', 'c'],['a', 'c'],['a', 'a']]
```

Which is clearly not, what I need. I guess, that's because `arr` itself mutates somehow in the process.

I know, I could use some `splice()` or something else, but I try to figure out how to make this one work properly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm... not sure what you mean by "where each item is a remainder from picking items out of initial array"

Comment: `[].map()` doesn't mutate, it returns a new array.

Comment: @spencer.sm : if you start with `['a','b','c']` and throw the first item out of that array it will give you `['b','c']`, if you throw out the second one, you're left with `['a','c']` and so on.

Comment: @dandavis : I'm aware of that, my guess was `arr` is somehow affected by destructuring

Comment: @SnailMass So what is the desired logic? return pairs with 1 missing item? is this only relevant for an array with length of 3?

Comment: @Sagivb.g : You've got the point about the logic. The method should work for arbitrary array length

Comment: @SnailMass So you basically want to convert array to pairs (tuple)?

Comment: `map()` doesn't mutate unless we mutate inside the map operation. This `arr[i]` on the left hand side of the assignment statement is what mangles the `arr`. It sets the each element (during each iteration) to the value of `a`;

Comment: This isn't a good use case for destructuring.

Comment: @zfrisch : mdn tutorial on that matter (destructuring, I mean) uses broadly in its example section destructuring array into its particular item and the rest part of it, which is exactly what I'm trying to achieve here, as an evidence you might find [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56601965/11648925) of the answers below. Probably, I could've come up with something similar, but that wouldn't be event close that compact as my above attempt (if it worked, of course :)

Comment: Well if `fancy` destructuring is what you were after, @Nina answer is what you should accept then. I doubt it gets more `creative` than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code will always remove the first element from array. You can convert array into object and then use Bracket Notation `[]` to specify the index to be removed. And then return values of object.

```js
let arr = ['a','b','c'];

const res = arr.map((_,i) => {
  let {[i]:removed,...rest} = Object.assign({},arr);
  return Object.values(rest)
})
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the code doesn't produce the desired outcome (not even close).

Comment: That's interesting [ _Your code, obviously, delivers expected result._ ] - not on Safari 12.1.1 on MacOS latest. I get: `["a","b","c"]` times three

Comment: @RandyCasburn isn't `[['b','c'],['a','c'],['a','b']]` the expected result?

Comment: @RandyCasburn : for both my FF and Chrome it works properly

Comment: @RandyCasburn - Safari doesn't support computed property names in destructuring yet.

Comment: ohhh, you treated the Array Index as a standard object parameter.  Clever

Comment: because of my obsession with one-liners, I would end up with something, like `const res = arr.map((_,i) => (({[i]:__,...rest} = Object.assign({},arr)), Object.values(rest)))`, however, thank you for showing the way

Comment: @SnailMass Look at Nina Scholz answer for the 1-liner. It destructures the array in `map`'s arguments.

Answer (score 5):

You could directly destructure the array and remove the item at the actual index.

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    result = array.map((_, i, { [i]: __, ...a }) => Object.values(a));

console.log(result); // ab ac bc
```

Comment: This is fantastic.